# Telegram API Пост с несколькими картинками

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, telegram

Вот таким способом отправляю пост и все работает отлично:

```
 public static async void bw_DoWork1()
    {

        botClient = new TelegramBotClient("APIKEY");
        Message[] messages = await botClient.SendMediaGroupAsync(
                       chatId: "@11",
                       inputMedia: new[]
                       {
                         new InputMediaPhoto("https://github.com/TelegramBots/book/raw/master/src/docs/photo-ara.jpg"),
                         new InputMediaPhoto("https://github.com/TelegramBots/book/raw/master/src/docs/photo-ara.jpg"),
                         new InputMediaPhoto("https://github.com/TelegramBots/book/raw/master/src/docs/photo-ara.jpg"),
                         new InputMediaPhoto(new InputMedia("https://github.com/TelegramBots/book/raw/master/src/docs/photo-ara.jpg"))
                         {
                          Caption = "Bot"
                         },

                       }
                   );

    }
```

Пробую inputMedia передать List:
public List Photo = new List();

```
  public async void bw_DoWork1(Post post)
    {
            botClient = new TelegramBotClient("APIKEY");
            Message[] messages = await botClient.SendMediaGroupAsync(
                           chatId: "@11",
                           inputMedia: (IEnumerable<IAlbumInputMedia>)post.Photo

                       );
    }
```

Получаю исключение:
System.InvalidCastException: "Не удалось привести тип объекта "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]" к типу "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Telegram.Bot.Types.IAlbumInputMedia]"."

Пробовал делать   `public List<IAlbumInputMedia> Photo = new List<IAlbumInputMedia>();`
Но тогда не выходит записать в List строку с ссылкой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас `List<string>` в исключении, а должен быть `List<IAlbumInputMedia>`.

Попробуйте так для `List<string>`

```cs
inputMedia: post.Photo.Select(x => new InputMediaPhoto(x))
```

Comment: Работает, спасибо